# Deriving the representation (1/2,1/2) of the Lorentz Group using Van der Waerden notation

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics

I'm trying to follow [Schwichtenberg's (Physics from Symmetry, Springer, 2nd edition, page 80)](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-19201-7#otherversion=9783319192017) method to derive the representation $(1/2,1/2)$ of the Lorentz Group. A brief overview follows:

- We find representations of SU(2), given by an integer or half integer *j*.
- Through complexification, we see that the Lorentz Group SO(1,3) is equivalent to two copies of SU(2).
- Before studying the (1/2,1/2) representation, we study the (1/2,0) and (0,1/2) representations (the two 2D representations) that correspond to a left-chiral spinor and a right-chiral spinor, respectively. Furthermore, these spinors are denoted with a lower undotted index and an upper dotted index, respectively (this is known as Van der Waerden notation). Where $\chi $ denotes a spinor:
  $$\chi _L=\chi _a \;\;\;\;\Big|\;\;\;\;  \chi _R=\chi ^{\dot{a}}\tag{1}$$
- In his proof, he mentions the fact that the representation has the following property
  $$(1/2,1/2)=(1/2,0)\otimes (0,1/2) \tag{2}$$
- We start by acknowledging that the object (let's call it $v$) that's going to be transformed by this representation (we will act on this object) will transform differently, and without interference, under each of the two copies of SU(2) in this representation.
- Then "the object will have 2 indices, each transforming under a separate two-dimensional copy of $\mathfrak{su}2$" and he writes
  $$v^{\dot{b}}_a\tag{3}$$

Why do we pick the indices to be that way? (By this I mean that I would have naturally picked two letters without much thought, rather than letters that may/may not be dotted and that may be an upper or lower index) Does eq. (2) have to do with it?

I have been reading on building representations through tensor products but I can't seem to connect these two ideas.

Furthermore, he says "Instead of examining $v^{\dot{b}}_a$, let's examine $v_{a\dot{b}}$", and object that we get from *lowering an index* using the *spinor metric*. We do this because the basis will then match with the Pauli Matrices. How do we know that the lower indices have a basis given by the Pauli Matrices? And thus why do upper indices have a different basis?

The rest of his method is clear. I just haven't been able to understand these few lines that motivate the rest. Thanks!

Comment: Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/770284/2451